# ¿Porque no me funciona el evento pageindexchanging gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hola tengo un gridview en asp .net y uso el siguiente codigo  para cambiar de pagina en el griview y no funciona.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="grid1_PageIndexChanging"   
PageSize="7" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
            FillGrid();
       }
    }

void FillGrid() {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tabla where cod_u='"+Session["Cod_u"]+"', con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid1.Visible = true;
            grid1.DataSource = dt;
           grid1.DataBind();
        }

 protected void grid1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

       grid1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        FillGrid();
    }
```

Tambien lo he intentado de esta forma:

```
protected void grid1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
      FillGrid();
       grid1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      grid1.DataBind();
    }
```

y no funciona.

Gracias por leer

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el método FillGrid() para ver lo que hace? ¿A qué te refieres con "no funciona"?¿Se produce una excepción?¿Aparece la paginación y no cambia de página?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y añadi el codigo, simplemente no hace nada, no marca errores y produce ninguna excepcion

Comment: Acabo de probar con tu primer código y funciona sin problemas. ¿Cuáles son los datos de la tabla? La Select te devuelve datos, ¿no?

Comment: esta rarisimo porque a mi no me funciona :c, asi es el select solo utilizo solo para que me muestre datos en el gridview de acuerdo al usuario que haya iniciado sesion

Comment: ¿Has debugeado para ver si entra en el método grid1_PageIndexChanging?

Comment: @Kiko_L hola ya lo he depurado y no entra en el metodo :O

Comment: Prueba a eliminar el método a crearlo de nuevo

Comment: Y lo intente pero nada... en las propiedas del gridview hay una que dice PageIndex y tiene un valor 0 por defecto, sera que tengo que poner algo ahi..? :c

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74824/discussion-between-sunflower-and-kiko-l).