# ¿Porque no se ve mi crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crystal-reports

tengo un proyecto webform en asp.net con c #, trabajo con formularios web. He agregado un Gridview para mostrar los datos de una consulta SQL y quiero mostrarlos en un crystal report. Pero sucede que al ejecutarlo no aparece y dar click al boton no se muestra nada. ¿Porque sera?

webconfig

```html
<system.web>
  <configuration>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cn" connectionString="Data bla bla" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.x"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

webform.aspx

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="/aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/CrystalReportWebF rmViewer3/images/tree/" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="/aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/CrystalReportWebFormViewer3/images/toolbar/" />
```

webform.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
            FillGrid();
       }
    }

void FillGrid(){
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table where cod_user='"+ 
Session["Cod_user"]+"'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridview1.Visible = true;
gridview1.DataSource = dt;
gridview1.DataBind();
con.Close();}

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ DsRF ds = new DsRF(); //DsRF es el dataset  lo cree agregando un nuevo elemento al proyecto y ahi mismo cree la tabla dt_RF

DataTable dt_RF = ds.Tables.Add("dt_RF");//aqui agrego la tabla al dataset 

foreach (DataControlField column in gridview1.Columns)
{
        dt_RF.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, typeof(string));
        }
foreach (GridViewRow dgr in gridview1.Rows)
{
        dt_RF.Rows.Add(gridview1.Rows[0].Cells.Cast<TableCell>().Select(c => c.Text));
       }

ReportDocument oRep = new ReportDocument();
oRep.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Proyecto/mycrystal.rpt"));
oRep.SetDataSource(ds);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRep; }}
```

Comment: sunflower te sugiero leas [ask] para formular una pregunta, la comunidad ha reportado que tienes varias preguntas que en realidad pueden ser una misma: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148563/porque-no-me-funciona-el-evento-pageindexchanging-gridview realiza correctamente una pregunta y obtendrás la ayuda adecuada, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate si esto te funciona. Tiene que agregar `using System.Linq;` en caso que aún no lo tengas:

```
var table = new DataTable();

foreach(DataControlField column in gridView1.Columns)
{
    table.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, typeof(string));
}
foreach (GridViewRow dgr in gridview1.Rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().Select(c => c.Text));
}
```

Comment: una pregunta esta linea  table.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, typeof(string)); la tengo que poner (en mi caso) 13 veces?

Comment: No, ya está iterando por el array de columns

Comment: Hola gracias, lo he probado, no me manda excepciones ni errores ni nada, pero no me muestra el reporte crystal

Comment: Hay una parte en tu código que no está muy clara, estas agregando la tabla al dataset?

Comment: lo que quiero es pasar el gridview a un dataset para mostrarlo en el crystal report

Comment: @sunflower en tu codigo veo que creas un `DsRF ds = new DsRF();` pero no veo que le agregues la tabla a lo que sea que fuese `DsRF`

Comment: DsRF es un dataset que creé, y en él creé la tabla

Comment: Podrías reformatear el código un poco en la pregunta? para que se vea claro donde creas el dataset y donde la tabla

Comment: Hola, ya lo he modificado como lo tengo ahora mismo

Comment: lo creé asi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLGWCoOkc6U pero yo no use el codigo de ese video porque lo que yo necesito es pasar un gridview al reporte

Comment: Fijate que ahi cambié mi codigo (estaba siempre sacando de Rows[0]) cambia eso y luego antes de mandar la info a Crystal fíjate si el DataTable tiene datos

Comment: creo que el codigo ya esta bien, al menos eso quiero pensar, podria ser problema del crystalreportviewer ....